# opensaml assertion signature validation

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have a SAML 2 response with one assertion which is signed and the response itself has signed again. I use below code to validate the signature profile of the response.

```
SAMLSignatureProfileValidator signatureProfileValidator = new SAMLSignatureProfileValidator();
signatureProfileValidator.validate(response.getSignature());
```

And below code block to validate signature.

```
SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(validatingCredential);
signatureValidator.validate(response.getSignature());
```

But I believe that these things validate the response signature and the response signature profile only. **Do I need to validate the assertion signature as well?** I have tried validating assertion signature using below code block. But it gives me the ValidationException which means it is not valid. But it should be.

```
SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(validatingCredential);
signatureValidator.validate(assertion.getSignature());
```

Comment: What does the Validationexception say?

Comment: I use the same private key to sign the assertion and the response. If I validate only the response signature, is gets successfully validated. But If i try to validate the assertion signature with the same credential which was success with the response it gives the following exception.

org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:79)

anyway Thanks Stefan.

Comment: could you post the code where you do signing and verification on https://gist.github.com/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/akalanka/58c72c48763daa94ad6e
I have put a lot of log messages there. Please ignore them. My last question. Do I really have to validate the assertion signature as well. Is it a common practice? I saw a lot of response signature validations. But no assertion signature validations.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be compliant, (and if I'm reading the spec correctly) you do need to validate both signatures. I believe the SAML 2.0 Profiles doc says that when processing the SAMLResponse, the SP must "validate any signatures present". See Sect 4.1.4.3  Message Processing Rules in the [SAML 2.0 Profiles doc](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf).